# Teradata/PHP/ODBC loop through results

Tags: php, odbc, teradata

I have a simple query:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 15 * from (SELECT * from table);";
```

If I *know* the names of the headers in the table, I can loop through the output like so:

```
  /* Execute */
  $query = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

  /* Build Array */
  while(odbc_fetch_row($query)){                      
    $x['a']   = odbc_result($query,'COLUMN_HEADER_A'); 
    $x['b']  = odbc_result($query,'COLUMN_HEADER_B');

    $list[] = $x;       
  }
}
```

Then I've got the results in my `$list[]` array and I can do something like this to see stuff:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
echo "</pre>";
```

If I *don't* know the names of the column headers however, I can call them using the following syntax: `odbc_result($query, 1);`, but I still don't know what they're called, or how many there are. How do I do a simple output of my query to display EACH column header along with its data?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:  using the `odbc_num_fields` and `odbc_field_name` options:

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($query)){                      
    for ($i=1; $i <= odbc_num_fields($query); $i++) {
      echo "<pre>";
      echo odbc_field_name($query, $i);
      echo "<br>";
      echo odbc_result($query, $i);
      echo "</pre>";    
    }                       
  }
```